# How to fix the error in Internet Explorer when loading json file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer, getjson

I have `JSON` file with congress representatives. When I load this file in Chrome or Firefox browser everything works just fine. If I try the same code in IE Edge/11/10 then I'm not any error but my code is not outputting data in the console. Then I tried to use `Ajax/JQuery` to load the data. This behaved the same in Chrome and Firefox but in IE I'm getting an error message:

```
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
File: test.html
[object Object]
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      readyState: 4,
      responseText: "[{"rep_name":"","row_id":550},{"rep_name":"Ferguson, A.","row_id":1},{"rep_name":"Kuster, Ann","row_id":2},{"rep_name":"Dent, Charles","row_id":3},{"rep_name":"Flores, Bill","row_id":4},{"rep_name":"Lujan Grisham, Michelle","row_id":5},{"rep_name":"Bishop, Sanford","row_id":6},{"rep_name":"","row_id":7},{"rep_name":"Flores, Bill","row_id":8},{"rep_name":"LoBiondo, Frank","row_id":9},{"rep_name":"Cole, Tom","row_id":10},{"rep_name":"","row_id":11},{"rep_name":"Burgess, Michael","row_id":12},{"rep_name":"Brown, Anthony","row_id":13},{"rep_name":"Lujan Grisham, Michelle","row_id":14},{"rep_name":"Abraham, Ralph","row_id":15},{"rep_name":"Barton, Joe","row_id":16},{"rep_name":"","row_id":17},{"rep_name":"Hice, Jody","row_id":18},{"rep_name":"Allen, Rick","row_id":19},{"rep_name":"","row_id":20},{"rep_name":"Stefanik, Elise","row_id":21},{"rep_name":"Bost, Mike","row_id":22},{"rep_name":"Loebsack, David","row_id":23},{"rep_name":"McMorris Rodgers, Cathy","row_id":24},{"rep_name":"Thornberry, Mac","row_id":25},{"re",
      status: 200,
      statusText: "OK"
   }

parsererror
SyntaxError: Expected '}'
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      description: "Expected '}'",
      message: "Expected '}'",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      number: -2146827279,
      stack: "SyntaxError: Expected '}'
   at ajaxConvert (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js:8787:8)
   at done (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js:9255:4)
   at Anonymous function (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js:9548:9)"
   }
```

```js
/*$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('data/test-ie.json', function(data) { // Test IE
        console.log(data);
    });
});*/

var test = [{
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 550
}, {
  "rep_name": "Ferguson, A.",
  "row_id": 1
}, {
  "rep_name": "Kuster, Ann",
  "row_id": 2
}, {
  "rep_name": "Dent, Charles",
  "row_id": 3
}, {
  "rep_name": "Flores, Bill",
  "row_id": 4
}, {
  "rep_name": "Lujan Grisham, Michelle",
  "row_id": 5
}, {
  "rep_name": "Bishop, Sanford",
  "row_id": 6
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 7
}, {
  "rep_name": "Flores, Bill",
  "row_id": 8
}, {
  "rep_name": "LoBiondo, Frank",
  "row_id": 9
}, {
  "rep_name": "Cole, Tom",
  "row_id": 10
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 11
}, {
  "rep_name": "Burgess, Michael",
  "row_id": 12
}, {
  "rep_name": "Brown, Anthony",
  "row_id": 13
}, {
  "rep_name": "Lujan Grisham, Michelle",
  "row_id": 14
}, {
  "rep_name": "Abraham, Ralph",
  "row_id": 15
}, {
  "rep_name": "Barton, Joe",
  "row_id": 16
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 17
}, {
  "rep_name": "Hice, Jody",
  "row_id": 18
}, {
  "rep_name": "Allen, Rick",
  "row_id": 19
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 20
}, {
  "rep_name": "Stefanik, Elise",
  "row_id": 21
}, {
  "rep_name": "Bost, Mike",
  "row_id": 22
}, {
  "rep_name": "Loebsack, David",
  "row_id": 23
}, {
  "rep_name": "McMorris Rodgers, Cathy",
  "row_id": 24
}, {
  "rep_name": "Thornberry, Mac",
  "row_id": 25
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 549
}, {
  "rep_name": "Emmer, Tom",
  "row_id": 26
}, {
  "rep_name": "Coffman, Mike",
  "row_id": 27
}, {
  "rep_name": "LaMalfa, Doug",
  "row_id": 28
}, {
  "rep_name": "Crist, Charlie",
  "row_id": 29
}, {
  "rep_name": "Higgins, Clay",
  "row_id": 30
}, {
  "rep_name": "Conyers, John",
  "row_id": 31
}, {
  "rep_name": "Hultgren, Randy",
  "row_id": 32
}, {
  "rep_name": "Tipton, Scott",
  "row_id": 33
}, {
  "rep_name": "Womack, Steve",
  "row_id": 34
}, {
  "rep_name": "Kuster, Ann",
  "row_id": 35
}, {
  "rep_name": "Lewis, John",
  "row_id": 36
}, {
  "rep_name": "Gallagher, Mike",
  "row_id": 37
}, {
  "rep_name": "McCaul, Michael",
  "row_id": 38
}, {
  "rep_name": "Meadows, Mark",
  "row_id": 39
}, {
  "rep_name": "Barletta, Lou",
  "row_id": 40
}, {
  "rep_name": "Upton, Fred",
  "row_id": 41
}, {
  "rep_name": "Neal, Richard",
  "row_id": 42
}, {
  "rep_name": "Messer, Luke",
  "row_id": 43
}, {
  "rep_name": "Cuellar, Henry",
  "row_id": 44
}, {
  "rep_name": "Long, Billy",
  "row_id": 45
}, {
  "rep_name": "Wasserman Schultz, Debbie",
  "row_id": 46
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 546
}, {
  "rep_name": "DeLauro, Rosa",
  "row_id": 47
}, {
  "rep_name": "Moulton, Seth",
  "row_id": 48
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 49
}, {
  "rep_name": "Jayapal, Pramila",
  "row_id": 50
}, {
  "rep_name": "Panetta, Jimmy",
  "row_id": 51
}, {
  "rep_name": "Byrne, Bradley",
  "row_id": 52
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 53
}, {
  "rep_name": "Poliquin, Bruce",
  "row_id": 54
}, {
  "rep_name": "Palmer, Gary",
  "row_id": 55
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 56
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 57
}, {
  "rep_name": "Polis, Jared",
  "row_id": 58
}, {
  "rep_name": "Turner, Michael",
  "row_id": 59
}, {
  "rep_name": "DeSantis, Ron",
  "row_id": 60
}, {
  "rep_name": "Larsen, Rick",
  "row_id": 61
}, {
  "rep_name": "Bucshon, Larry",
  "row_id": 62
}, {
  "rep_name": "Shimkus, John",
  "row_id": 63
}, {
  "rep_name": "Cooper, Jim",
  "row_id": 64
}, {
  "rep_name": "Simpson, Michael",
  "row_id": 65
}, {
  "rep_name": "Keating, William",
  "row_id": 66
}, {
  "rep_name": "Weber, Randy",
  "row_id": 67
}, {
  "rep_name": "González-Colón, Jenniffer",
  "row_id": 68
}, {
  "rep_name": "Vela, Filemon",
  "row_id": 69
}, {
  "rep_name": "Walberg, Tim",
  "row_id": 70
}, {
  "rep_name": "Graves, Garret",
  "row_id": 71
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 72
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 73
}, {
  "rep_name": "Brownley, Julia",
  "row_id": 74
}, {
  "rep_name": "Moulton, Seth",
  "row_id": 75
}, {
  "rep_name": "Harris, Andy",
  "row_id": 76
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 77
}, {
  "rep_name": "Hultgren, Randy",
  "row_id": 78
}, {
  "rep_name": "Wilson, Joe",
  "row_id": 79
}, {
  "rep_name": "Joyce, David",
  "row_id": 80
}, {
  "rep_name": "Bera, Ami",
  "row_id": 81
}, {
  "rep_name": "Frelinghuysen, Rodney",
  "row_id": 82
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 83
}, {
  "rep_name": "Fleischmann, Charles",
  "row_id": 84
}, {
  "rep_name": "Biggs, Andy",
  "row_id": 85
}, {
  "rep_name": "Brat, Dave",
  "row_id": 86
}, {
  "rep_name": "Sanford, Mark",
  "row_id": 87
}, {
  "rep_name": "Huffman, Jared",
  "row_id": 88
}, {
  "rep_name": "Blum, Rod",
  "row_id": 89
}, {
  "rep_name": "McKinley, David",
  "row_id": 90
}, {
  "rep_name": "Turner, Michael",
  "row_id": 91
}, {
  "rep_name": "Flores, Bill",
  "row_id": 92
}, {
  "rep_name": "Pittenger, Robert",
  "row_id": 93
}, {
  "rep_name": "McCarthy, Kevin",
  "row_id": 94
}, {
  "rep_name": "Tiberi, Patrick",
  "row_id": 95
}, {
  "rep_name": "Shimkus, John",
  "row_id": 96
}, {
  "rep_name": "Takano, Mark",
  "row_id": 97
}, {
  "rep_name": "Flores, Bill",
  "row_id": 98
}, {
  "rep_name": "Lamborn, Doug",
  "row_id": 99
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 100
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 101
}, {
  "rep_name": "Bost, Mike",
  "row_id": 102
}, {
  "rep_name": "Clyburn, James",
  "row_id": 103
}, {
  "rep_name": "Yoho, Ted",
  "row_id": 104
}, {
  "rep_name": "Farenthold, Blake",
  "row_id": 105
}, {
  "rep_name": "Vargas, Juan",
  "row_id": 106
}, {
  "rep_name": "Mooney, Alexander",
  "row_id": 107
}, {
  "rep_name": "Scott, Austin",
  "row_id": 108
}, {
  "rep_name": "Massie, Thomas",
  "row_id": 109
}, {
  "rep_name": "Duffy, Sean",
  "row_id": 110
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 111
}, {
  "rep_name": "Brady, Kevin",
  "row_id": 112
}, {
  "rep_name": "Cartwright, Matt",
  "row_id": 113
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 114
}, {
  "rep_name": "Buck, Ken",
  "row_id": 115
}, {
  "rep_name": "Barton, Joe",
  "row_id": 116
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 545
}, {
  "rep_name": "Murphy, Stephanie",
  "row_id": 117
}, {
  "rep_name": "Johnson, Eddie",
  "row_id": 118
}, {
  "rep_name": "Beatty, Joyce",
  "row_id": 119
}, {
  "rep_name": "Loebsack, David",
  "row_id": 120
}, {
  "rep_name": "Comstock, Barbara",
  "row_id": 121
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 122
}, {
  "rep_name": "Buck, Ken",
  "row_id": 123
}, {
  "rep_name": "Lawrence, Brenda",
  "row_id": 124
}, {
  "rep_name": "Barton, Joe",
  "row_id": 125
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 126
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 127
}, {
  "rep_name": "Roby, Martha",
  "row_id": 128
}, {
  "rep_name": "Nolan, Richard",
  "row_id": 129
}, {
  "rep_name": "Hultgren, Randy",
  "row_id": 130
}, {
  "rep_name": "King, Steve",
  "row_id": 131
}, {
  "rep_name": "Johnson, Mike",
  "row_id": 132
}, {
  "rep_name": "Burgess, Michael",
  "row_id": 133
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 540
}, {
  "rep_name": "Schweikert, David",
  "row_id": 134
}, {
  "rep_name": "Brady, Kevin",
  "row_id": 135
}, {
  "rep_name": "Esty, Elizabeth",
  "row_id": 136
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 137
}, {
  "rep_name": "Duffy, Sean",
  "row_id": 138
}, {
  "rep_name": "Gaetz, Matt",
  "row_id": 139
}, {
  "rep_name": "Tipton, Scott",
  "row_id": 140
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 141
}, {
  "rep_name": "O'Rourke, Beto",
  "row_id": 142
}, {
  "rep_name": "Aguilar, Pete",
  "row_id": 143
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 144
}, {
  "rep_name": "Ryan, Paul",
  "row_id": 145
}, {
  "rep_name": "Kelly, Mike",
  "row_id": 146
}, {
  "rep_name": "Harris, Andy",
  "row_id": 147
}, {
  "rep_name": "DeFazio, Peter",
  "row_id": 148
}, {
  "rep_name": "Rutherford, John",
  "row_id": 149
}, {
  "rep_name": "Bucshon, Larry",
  "row_id": 150
}, {
  "rep_name": "Kennedy, Joseph",
  "row_id": 151
}, {
  "rep_name": "Butterfield, G.",
  "row_id": 152
}, {
  "rep_name": "Payne, Donald",
  "row_id": 153
}, {
  "rep_name": "Rooney, Francis",
  "row_id": 154
}, {
  "rep_name": "Webster, Daniel",
  "row_id": 155
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 156
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 157
}, {
  "rep_name": "Panetta, Jimmy",
  "row_id": 158
}, {
  "rep_name": "Rouzer, David",
  "row_id": 159
}, {
  "rep_name": "Paulsen, Erik",
  "row_id": 160
}, {
  "rep_name": "Delaney, John",
  "row_id": 161
}, {
  "rep_name": "Biggs, Andy",
  "row_id": 162
}, {
  "rep_name": "Hastings, Alcee",
  "row_id": 163
}, {
  "rep_name": "Grijalva, Raúl",
  "row_id": 164
}, {
  "rep_name": "Ross, Dennis",
  "row_id": 165
}, {
  "rep_name": "Clyburn, James",
  "row_id": 166
}, {
  "rep_name": "Luján, Ben",
  "row_id": 167
}, {
  "rep_name": "Crist, Charlie",
  "row_id": 168
}, {
  "rep_name": "Levin, Sander",
  "row_id": 169
}, {
  "rep_name": "Jenkins, Lynn",
  "row_id": 170
}, {
  "rep_name": "Tonko, Paul",
  "row_id": 171
}, {
  "rep_name": "Webster, Daniel",
  "row_id": 172
}, {
  "rep_name": "King, Peter",
  "row_id": 173
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 174
}, {
  "rep_name": "Womack, Steve",
  "row_id": 175
}, {
  "rep_name": "Buck, Ken",
  "row_id": 176
}, {
  "rep_name": "Granger, Kay",
  "row_id": 177
}, {
  "rep_name": "Lewis, John",
  "row_id": 178
}, {
  "rep_name": "Royce, Edward",
  "row_id": 179
}, {
  "rep_name": "Banks, Jim",
  "row_id": 180
}, {
  "rep_name": "Barton, Joe",
  "row_id": 181
}, {
  "rep_name": "Ross, Dennis",
  "row_id": 182
}, {
  "rep_name": "Womack, Steve",
  "row_id": 183
}, {
  "rep_name": "Marshall, Roger",
  "row_id": 184
}, {
  "rep_name": "Grijalva, Raúl",
  "row_id": 185
}, {
  "rep_name": "McMorris Rodgers, Cathy",
  "row_id": 186
}, {
  "rep_name": "Franks, Trent",
  "row_id": 187
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 188
}, {
  "rep_name": "Gohmert, Louie",
  "row_id": 189
}, {
  "rep_name": "Tipton, Scott",
  "row_id": 190
}, {
  "rep_name": "Barton, Joe",
  "row_id": 191
}, {
  "rep_name": "Thompson, Bennie",
  "row_id": 192
}, {
  "rep_name": "Green, Al",
  "row_id": 193
}, {
  "rep_name": "Gowdy, Trey",
  "row_id": 194
}, {
  "rep_name": "DeSantis, Ron",
  "row_id": 195
}, {
  "rep_name": "Courtney, Joe",
  "row_id": 196
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 197
}, {
  "rep_name": "Marchant, Kenny",
  "row_id": 198
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 199
}, {
  "rep_name": "Gallagher, Mike",
  "row_id": 200
}, {
  "rep_name": "Smith, Adrian",
  "row_id": 201
}, {
  "rep_name": "Amash, Justin",
  "row_id": 202
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 203
}, {
  "rep_name": "Walker, Mark",
  "row_id": 204
}, {
  "rep_name": "Gowdy, Trey",
  "row_id": 205
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 206
}, {
  "rep_name": "Kelly, Trent",
  "row_id": 207
}, {
  "rep_name": "Carter, John",
  "row_id": 208
}, {
  "rep_name": "Bordallo, Madeleine",
  "row_id": 209
}, {
  "rep_name": "Gowdy, Trey",
  "row_id": 210
}, {
  "rep_name": "Grijalva, Raúl",
  "row_id": 211
}, {
  "rep_name": "Visclosky, Peter",
  "row_id": 212
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 535
}, {
  "rep_name": "Brat, Dave",
  "row_id": 213
}, {
  "rep_name": "Larson, John",
  "row_id": 214
}, {
  "rep_name": "Delaney, John",
  "row_id": 215
}, {
  "rep_name": "Aguilar, Pete",
  "row_id": 216
}, {
  "rep_name": "Bonamici, Suzanne",
  "row_id": 217
}, {
  "rep_name": "Palazzo, Steven",
  "row_id": 218
}, {
  "rep_name": "McHenry, Patrick",
  "row_id": 219
}, {
  "rep_name": "McKinley, David",
  "row_id": 220
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 221
}, {
  "rep_name": "Titus, Dina",
  "row_id": 222
}, {
  "rep_name": "",
  "row_id": 539
}, {
  "rep_name": "Pearce, Stevan",
  "row_id": 223
}]
console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I gave you a sample of data in the snippet. If you runt this in IE that might not be the best way to test the problem. If you copy the data to your local server in `.json` file and then load the data from there you will be able to reproduce the error. I'm not sure why this is breaking in IE. If anyone knows how to fix this problem please let me know.

**UPDATE**
I finally solved the problem. On the back end where I was generating `.json` file around `rep_name` column I used `URLEncodedFormat()` ColdFusion method. That fixed the problem and IE did not throw an error any more. In the output on the front end in JavaScript I used `decodeURIComponent(data['rep_name'])`. That was all I needed in order to fix this problem.

Comment: Try to change "row_id" values from int to string. I'm pretty sure that this should cause such kind of issue, because IE is following JSON standard, which says that value MUST BE 'string, array, or another object'

Comment: I forgot to mention that `row_id` is there just for testing purpose and I know `100%` that issue is in the `rep_name` fields. I have working json file and once I added `rep_name` then code started breaking in IE.

Comment: In this case I suggest to use any jsonlinter to ensure,  that your json has correct format and is valid.  Chrome and FF are much more smart then IE and can fix minor json issues on rendering.

Comment: @dganenco This is very frustrating since I'm looking over this file for the past few hours and trying different things but still the same error in IE. I used this site `https://jsonlint.com/` and copy past the json file data. Result was `Valid JSON`! I'm not sure what's wrong in IE...